# React - Remove empty DIV from return condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im trying to remove this empty `<div>` from html.

```
class ParentComp extends Component {
...

return (
      <div>
        {
          GlobalAppHandlerStore.getCurrentState().countryCode === this.props.countryCode ?
            this.props.children
            :
            ''
        }
      </div>
    );
```

Use case:

```
<ParentComp countryCode={COUNTRY_CODE.be.value}>
   <ItemConfigure {...this.props} />
</ParentComp>
```

It prints empty in case of no match.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the result you are getting and what you expect to show exactly? In any case, I would generally default to `null` instead of an empty string to ternary operators within the component JSX. E.g.: `condition ? <div>Content</div> : null`

Comment: but you can just do: GlobalAppHandlerStore.getCurrentState().countryCode === this.props.countryCode && ({this.props.children})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
render() {
    return GlobalAppHandlerStore.getCurrentState().countryCode === this.props.countryCode && (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
}
```